# How to validate something before installing local plugin in moodle

Tags: moodle, moodle-api, moodle-mobile, moodle-theme, moodle-boost

I have developed a local plugin and before installation i want to check if a certain plugin i.e. mod_attendance exists in the moodle, if it exists i want to continue with the normal installation else if the mod_attendance doesn't exist i want to return a error message and exit installation. My local plugin works on top of the mod_attendace plugin so i want to check if this plugin exists or not.

**I don't know which files to add or edit in my local plugin to add validations before installation.**

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your plugin's version.php, just declare that mod_attendance is a dependency for your plugin, then Moodle will take care of preventing it being installed without it.

```
$plugin->dependencies = ['mod_attendance' => ANY_VERSION];
```

See https://docs.moodle.org/dev/version.php for more details.